# Deleting rows in R conditionally

Tags: r, conditional-statements, delete-row

I have a data where the first column is a bunch of ID numbers (some repeat), and the second column is just a bunch of numbers. I need a way to keep each ID number only once based on the smallest number in the second column.

```
Row#   ID   Number
1      10     180
2      12     167
3      12     182
4      12     135
5      15     152
6      15     133
```

Ex: I only want to keep Row# 1, 4, and 6 here and delete the rest

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For selecting the row that has the minimum 'Number' for each 'ID' group, we can use one of the aggregating by group function.  A `base R` option is `aggregate`.  With `aggregate`, we can either use the 'formula' method or specify a `list` of grouping elements/variables with the `by` argument.  Using the `formula` method, we get the `min` value of 'Number' for each 'ID'.

```
aggregate(Number~ID, df1, FUN=min)
```

---

Or we can use a faster option with `data.table`.  Here, we convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'ID', we get the `min` value of "Number".

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, list(Number=min(Number)), by = ID]
```

Or this can be also done with `setorder` to `order` the 'Number' column and use `unique` with `by` option to select the first non-duplicated 'ID' row.  (from @David Arenburgs' comments)

```
 unique(setorder(setDT(df1), Number), by = "ID")
```

---

Or using `dplyr`, we group by 'ID' and get the subset rows with `summarise`.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   summarise(Number= min(Number))
```

---

Or we can use `sqldf` syntax to get the subset of data.

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf('select ID,
        min(Number) as Number
        from df1 
        group by ID')
```

#### Update

If there are multiple columns and you want to get the row based on the minimum value of 'Number' for each 'ID', you can use `which.min`.  Using `.I` will get the row index and that can be used for subsetting the rows.

```
setDT(df1)[df1[,  .I[which.min(Number)], by = ID]$V1]
```

---

Or with `dplyr` we use `slice` to filter out the rows that have the `min` value of 'Number' for each 'ID'

```
df1 %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>%
    slice(which.min(Number))
```

Comment: Or `unique(setorder(setDT(df1), Number), by = "ID")`. I also think you need `which.min` instead of `min` because it seems that OP *always* want to keep one row per `ID`. Btw, nice `sqldf` solution there :)

Comment: @DavidArenburg  Thanks, `min` keeps only the single value, but `which.min` will be more general when there are more columns.

Answer (score 2):

Or

```
do.call(rbind, 
lapply(split(df1, df1$ID), function(x) subset(x, Number == min(Number))))

#ID Number
#10 10    180
#12 12    135
#15 15    133
```